# What means the Error: "float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'"

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I have a Variable, in the Form:

```
X = array([<built-in function array>, 66.0, 98.0, ..., 244.0, 254.0, 255.0],      dtype=object)
```

If I want to fit them in a SVC classifier, the Error:

```
float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

What means this Error?
It comes on this line of code:

```
svm.fit(X,y)
```

What can I do  against this?
thank you

Comment: It means that an element of your array cannot be converted by `float`. How did you create your array?

Comment: You didn't wonder about the strange first item in your array?

Comment: I create it with the load_img module from keras. In this Array are many pictures stored

Comment: Yes, I wonder a little bit about it, but I dont use numpy so much. What means this?

Comment: You have an object dtype array - it has a lot of numbers, but also this `<...>` object which apparently is a function.  The classifier (from which module?) apparently expects an array of floats, and so tries to convert your array to that (with a `arr.astype(float)` or `np.array(arr, dtype=float)`).  So you need a clearer understanding of what you can feed the classifier, and what the `keras` load produces.

Comment: Please include code that builds the array in your question

Answer (score 0):

> What means the Error: “float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'”

The error means you are trying to convert an array to a floating point number. You have data that isn't a number and doesn't look like a number, and are trying to convert it to a number.

It's the same error as if you did this:

```
something=[]
float(something)
```

Python has no idea how to convert a list into a number.

Comment: @Meinnamegehtdichgarn: it's hard to say what you can do. It looks like you're getting data that you are  assuming your data is just numbers, but it is part numbers and part list of numbers. The solution might be to fix the code that gets the data, or fix the code that's converting the data.